# Как передать сразу много пропсов в реакт компонент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вопрос несложный, но я не могу найти никакой инфы в интернете об этом =(

есть

```
<div>
  {items.map( ({id, name, info, etc...}) => {<MyComp id={id} name={name} info={info} etc... />} ) }
</div>
```

а нужно что то в духе

```
<div>
  {items.map( itemProps => <MyComp {itemProps} /> ) }
</div>
```

Как это далается?

Comment: `<MyComp {...itemProps} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для передачи нескольких свойств в компонент можно воспользоваться [`spread attributes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)

```
<div>
  {items.map( itemProps => <MyComp {...itemProps} /> ) }
</div>
```